# Ternary Sequence of 1,3, 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence relation for the number of the sequences of 1s, 3s, and 5s whose terms sum to n with the condition of no subsequence of 135.

My approach.
Without condition(no subsequence of 135), it is
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-5} $$

Since 135's sum is 9,
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-5} - a_{n-9} $$

If I miss anything, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Does the prohibition on $135$ refer to those digits appearing consecutively?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes. It is